# Is this a suitable location for questions regarding how a character might realistic do something?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic

I would like to ask a question about how a fictional amateur journalist might obtain specific information from a (UK) private school. The universe is as close to ours as to require little other world building and I do not want to ask an off topic question and waste other people's time.

Comment: It sounds fine to me, as long as when you ask the question you give enough context. I at least can't think of a better SE site to ask it than this one.

Comment: In my opinion it's not a good question for Stack exchange. If I'm wrong, Writer SE is a better place because it's about a plot element.

Comment: I'm not so sure it'd be a better fit on Writers. [See their scope.](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (Which doesn't *really* say either way...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me this feels a little too far in the plot/character direction rather than worldbuilding.  However, it might be possible to turn it around so it's a worldbuilding question.  Instead of asking about how the journalist would research something, could you ask how schools of a certain type (which you'd describe in the question) would protect sensitive information from prying eyes?  That feels more like a question about the *world* to me.  Once you have that, you can then work out the plot of how your journalist would defeat their protections.

Does that help at all?